# Error deploying firebase functions on react native project

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I was testing out my cloud functions in my React Native project and ran into this issue where I'm told:

[image]

I found this strange since in the past I had successfully deployed my functions.

Here is the cloud function code which sets up a simple https request:

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
  // Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  const writeResult = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("general")
    .doc("spaces")
    .update({ original: original });

  // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
  res.json({ result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.` });
});
```

And here is my firestore where I'm trying to write to:
[image]

And when running this code:
 `firebase --debug deploy --only functions`

This is the error logs:

[image]

And here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Hi @Andy, could you please include your `package.json` to your question for us to further reproduce the issue. I tried to reproduce the error but I successfully deployed your function. Also, please refrain from posting a screenshot of code, post your code instead.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB Hi, I added my package.json along with making the edit you suggested. Thanks

Comment: If you go on GCP console, is there any error in the current version of the function, is the status of the function "active"?

Comment: I was able to solve this issue although I could not identify what the problem was. I deleted my functions folder along with the firebase.json file and then redid the process of installation with `firebase init functions`

Comment: @Andy fixed mine as well by deleteing firebase.json . Weird!